# How can I track the master branch of a new remote repository?

Tags: git

I have two remote in my local repository:

```
me@desktop:~/linux$ git remote 
linux-next
origin
```

When I do `git checkout linux-next/master` then I get the followint status:

```
me@desktop:~/linux$ git status
HEAD detached at linux-next/master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

How can I checkout the master of the second remote `linux-next` **AND** tracking that remote as a result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try

```
git branch -u Linux-next/master
```

if your git version is beyond 1.8.